# Why is Android Bluetooth keyboard dpad down not working with listview containing a header view?

Tags: android, listview, bluetooth

I have a list view that needs to support being navigable via a bluetooth keyboard. The list view also has a header view that needs to be navigable via the keyboard. The problem is when I press the down arrow, the focus is directed to a view above the list, in this example @+id/header . I need to press down as many times as there are list items for the focus to move to the list instead of going back and forth between the header and the list view's header...It's rather strange.

I've made a sample app to try and narrow the problem down to no avail. It's also worth noting if @+id/header is not focusable (for example when I made it a text view), the keyboard works as expected which, unfortunately, is not an option for me because my header needs to support bluetooth navigation.

Any help would be amazing, thanks.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.listviewtest;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private SimpleAdapter adapter;
    private List<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    private MyListView list;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        TextView empty = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.empty);

        // create the grid item mapping
        String[] from = new String[] {"rowid"};
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.item1};

        // prepare the list of all records
        data = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("rowid", "" + i);
            data.add(map);
        }

        // fill in the grid_item layout
        adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, data, R.layout.grid_item, from, to);

        list.addHeaderView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.grid_header, null));
        list.setEmptyView(empty);
        list.setItemsCanFocus(true);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/main"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:text="Header"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.DialogWindowTitle"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:onClick="toggleList"
        android:clickable="true"
    />

    <!-- ListView (grid_items) -->
    <ListView android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="I'm empty"
        android:gravity="center" 
        android:visibility="gone"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**grid_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/item1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:padding="20dp" />
```

**grid_header.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:focusable="false"
    style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/item1"
            android:text="button1"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:width="0dp"
            android:height="30dip"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle" />

        <TextView android:id="@+id/item2"
            android:text="button2"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:width="0dp"
            android:height="30dip"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle" />
</LinearLayout>
```